# Performing sequential ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I tried to perfrom two sequential ajax request like:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","data.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send('url=' + url);
var x=10;
var y=20;
xmlhttp.open("POST","datatest.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send('x=' + x, 'y=' + y);
```

Does not Give error, but says:

```
POST http://dev01.dev/data.php Aborted
```

And shows result of `echo` in datatest.php only. HOw can i get response from both data.php and datatest.php?

UPDATE:

`data.php` will give some result.

```
echo $result1;
```

`datatest.php` will give some result.

```
echo $result2;
```

I want to append above two result in `myDiv`.

If I do

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText1;
```

then

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText2;
```

It will replace the content. I want to append it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> HOw can i get response from both data.php and datatest.php?

Use a *separate* XHR object rather than attempting to reuse the existing one. Your current code *starts* a request, but then you do `xmlhttp.open("POST","datatest.php",true);` on that same XHR object again before the request has time to finish, so it gets aborted.

For example:

```
var xmlhttp1, xmlhttp2;
function getXHR() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else { // code for IE6, IE5
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
}
xmlhttp1 = getXHR();
xmlhttp1.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp1.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp1.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp1.responseText;
    }
};
xmlhttp1.open("POST", "data.php", true);
xmlhttp1.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp1.send('url=' + url);

var x = 10;
var y = 20;
xmlhttp2 = getXHR();
xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange = function () {
    // Presumably do someething with the result of this one, too
};
xmlhttp2.open("POST", "datatest.php", true);
xmlhttp2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp2.send('x=' + x, 'y=' + y);
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I append to `myDiv` in xmlhttp2 result also?

Comment: @Karimkhan: You're not *appending* to `myDiv` in your first request, you're *replacing* its content. Did you want to append (add to what's there) in both cases?